# How can I do safe split()

Tags: javascript

I have some object

```js
{
  title: "Some title",
  value: "Some value"
}
```

I store my object like a string with `:` separator:

```
`${title}:${value}`
```

But when I transform my string to object again I want to be sure that it is safe. Because `title` and `value` can contain separator `:`

```js
const [value, title] = string.split(":");
const obj = {
  value,
  title
}
```

How can I do it?

I think I need something like this:

```
`${replacer(title)}:${replacer(value)}`

const [value, title] = string.split(":");
const obj = {
  value: invertReplacer(value),
  title: invertReplacer(value)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use [JSON](https://json.org) with `JSON.stringify`/`JSON.parse`?

Comment: what is the problem in the existing implementation

Comment: @brk _“`title` and `value` can contain separator `:`”_.

Comment: Just use [`JSON.stringify(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Static_methods) instead.

Comment: @str yeah I think I will use your approach. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing objects like `${title}:${value}`, you could store object like `${title}${value}:${title.length}`. From that, you can extract the length of the title and split your string at the certain position.

Comment: That's an interesting idea... However, it may be better to strore the length before `${title}${value}`, in case if `value` contains `:`, like this: `${title.length}:${title}${value}`. `title.length` can not contain `:`...

Comment: It's a great idea. But I think I will use the `JSON.stringify/JSON.parse` instead. Thank you